# Given $E[X] \geq 0$ , and given $a$ and $b$ real numbers such that $a+b>0$ show that $p(X\geq a)\leq p( (X+b)^2\geq (a+b)^2)$

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, inequality

Problem: Given $E[X] \geq 0$ , and given $a$ and $b$ real numbers such that $a+b>0$ show that $p(X\geq a)\leq p( (X+b)^2\geq (a+b)^2)$

I couldn't find a way by the inequalities I could think of , either directly or by defining each of $p(X\geq a)$ and $p( (X+b)^2\geq (a+b)^2 )$ as $1-p(X<a)$ and $1-p( (X+b)^2<(a+b)^2 )$

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: Hey @Khan. Try to provide some context to the problem like where it comes from and what you were studying when it came up. Also, https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference here is a mathjax reference

Comment: Thank you for the edit and the basic information about writing mathematics For the context of the problem, it was a first question of a problem which aim is to prove the Paley Zygmund inequality, the  assumptions I mentioned were the only assumptions made for this first question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note the inclusion of events $[X\geq a]\subset [X+b\geq a+b]\subset [(X+b)^2\geq (a+b)^2]$. The last inclusion stems from $a+b\geq 0$ and implies $$P(X\geq a)\leq P((X+b)^2\geq (a+b)^2)$$